# Unjust treatment of both asker and reviewer

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing I came along [a question which is now closed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4203231) but I could save a screenshot:

> [image]

First I got very surprised about the `STOP! Look and Listen` blast. I feel unjustly treated here as the question does not at all not show any indication of spam. Then I took a second look to see if I may have overlooked something and found that this question as a whole is not treated well at all.

It's not a perfectly worded question, no doubt, but I have seen worse with good answers. It's really unfair IMO that this question was closed.

Honestly, I have the feeling that questions often get closed too easily, discouraging people to ask (especially those who don't speak english well and/or are too young to know better). We should teach not rule them.

**Additionally**: for the review I may have found a bug in the spam detection.

Comment: Are you on purpose trying to vote on python questions because in your profile I don't see python as one of your main tags. If you apply a filter (on the top next to the title 'close votes') reviewing becomes easier (and as a bonus the audits are easier to spot)

Comment: Well, it just happened to be a python question. Doesn't really matter for the discussion here.

Comment: Hmm, lots of downvotes and nobody cares to write why. This just confirms my complain here in a different way.

Comment: +7/-4 is not too bad, I would say. I guess they trigger on your statement about this being 'unjust'. If you reword your question to ask an explanation for the closure of this question and/or the quality of the audit the current answer still holds and wouldn't attract more down votes. But you're correct it sometimes just guessing why voters vote the way they do.

Answer (score 4):

The question is asking about relatively simple language constructs that 5 minutes of Googling should be able to answer. So while it is a valid question, it's not a good question for SO. And just because there are worse questions with better answers does not automatically make those questions suited for SO either; they may predate the stricter moderation policies.

Spam detection is done by an algorithm so it's never going to be 100% correct, hence why the message says "*possible* spam".

Comment: Maybe, but there must be at least a few real answers you can google for. The question was not marked as duplicate btw.

Comment: Not sure that a question being easy to google automatically makes it a bad question. One of the goals of stack exchange was to provide a home for definitive answers to questions of all levels, and essentially to have google linking to 'us' as the simple example that everyone can find with just 5 mins of searching.

Comment: Basic questions are perfectly fine as long as they're asked well.

Comment: SO should be *the* site found by that 5 minutes of Googling, not just place to ask when answer does not exist elsewhere. Also, using "complex" nested data structures can be tricky, a common novice problem, and good SO content (even if this particular question got snuffed out before being edited for clarity).